# No signature of method BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

I am having a problem when trying to match a password of a user using `spring-security-core:2.0-RC4` with `Grails 2.3.3`.

I'm getting the following error when doing `passwordEncoder.matches(rawPassword, encodedPassword)`

```
No signature of method grails.plugin.springsecurity.authentication.encoding.BCryptPasswordEncoder.matches() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
```

I've checked the [BCryptPasswordEncoder source](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/authentication/encoding/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java) to search for clues and ended up in [PasswordEncoder class definition](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/PasswordEncoder.html).

The import in [BCryptPasswordEncoder](https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/src/java/grails/plugin/springsecurity/authentication/encoding/BCryptPasswordEncoder.java) looks wrong though as the new PasswordEncoder is in `org.springframework.security.crypto.password`.

Doing `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(rawPassword, encodedPassword, null)` works (as in, there are no errors), but I don't know how to get the salt.

Is this working properly? If so, how do I get the salt?

EDIT:
I tried using `NullSaltSource` too but it gives me the error:

```
Salt value must be null when used with crypto module PasswordEncoder
```

Comment: Apparently I don't think I had anything really problematic. All I needed to do was swap the encoded with the raw password, like so:
passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(encodedPassword, rawPassword, null) works.

Comment: The next code snippet appears in the docs: if (!passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(user.password, password, null /*salt*/)) {
      flash.message = 'Current password is incorrect'
      render view: 'passwordExpired', model: [username: session['SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_USERNAME']]
      return
   }

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, you can't use a salt with bcrypt. That's fine though - the algorithm is very robust and acts as if it's using a salt already.

The point of a salt is to ensure that if you and I have the same password, we don't have the same hashed password (assuming we each have our own salt value). Unsalted passwords cannot be de-hashed, but it's possible to create a table of hashes for all combination of passwords up to a certain length and use that as a lookup to find the cleartext password given a hash. Do an internet search for "rainbow table" and you'll find sites that have lookup tables for MD5, SHA-1 and other algorithms.

If you run `encodePassword` with a null salt value using bcrypt you'll get a different hash string for each run. The `isPasswordValid` method implementation with simpler algorithms usually hashes the cleartext password with the provided salt if there is one, and checks that this value is the same as the stored hash. But with bcrypt that's not sufficient, so it has the logic to verify that they are *equivalent*, but not necessarily equal.

The plugin uses a mix of implementations of the two interfaces for backwards compatibility, and will drop support for the old interface in a future release.

Comment: So, would `passwordEncoder.isPasswordValid(rawPassword, encodedPassword, null)` work? I tried to check if two equal passwords matched but the result of `isPasswordValid` says they aren't.